# has_many and belongs_to on other fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, primary-key, models

I have two models that have a `token` field. They are called `Ticket` and `Message`.

My ticket model looks like so.

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UUIDHelper

  has_many :messages, :primary_key => "token", :foreign_key => "token"
end
```

Now I'm creating a new message from a rake task like this.

```
new_message = Message.new
new_message.token = uuid
new_message.save
```

My token gets saved to the message but it then returns an empty set of messages from ticket like so

```
@ticket.messages
```

I asume my ticket model is not quite right.

Comment: `Ticket.messages` doesn't make any sense. `Ticket` is the model class. You can't call `messages` on that; you can only call it on an instance of the class.

Comment: what if to add `:class_name => 'Message'` to `has_many`?

Comment: sorry @BenLee i just fixed the typo

Comment: @JosephLeBrech, you should confirm that `@ticket.token == uuid`.

Comment: Also, maybe you should be more clear about you mean when you say you "cannot load the collection" -- does it return an empty set? Runtime error? Something else?

Comment: Have you reload de @ticket after create the new_message ?

Comment: the message gets saved to the database with the token field saved, that field should then link the models together

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, after using the rails console I noticed that the token wasn't there but instead there was a reference to a ruby Match object. I had forgotten to set the result of a match to string and it wasn't saving the token to the model.